# Why did Munkres consider $\phi$ as a function which is differentiable on an open interval containing $I$ to apply the mean-value theorem to $\phi$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

***Why did Munkres consider $\phi$ as a function which is differentiable on an open interval containing $I$ to apply the mean-value theorem to $\phi$?***

I think it is obvious that $\phi$ is continuous on $[0,h_j]$ or $[h_j,0]$ and differentiable on $(0,h_j)$ or $(h_j,0)$.

[image]